# How do I exclude values within a range in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

If I wanted to select observations with a variable within the range 1000-2000 I would do this:

```r
filteredData <- unfilteredData%>% filter(variable %in% (1000:2000))
```

But how do I EXCLUDE variables within the range 1000-2000? I only want those <1000 or >2000

Comment: `filter(!(variable %in% (1000:2000)))` is one way, but this probably isn't ideal. You can do two filters, <1000 and >2000

Comment: In my experience, you don't even need the extra set of parenthesis. Some find them helpful for legibility, however.

Comment: `!between(variable, 1000, 2000)` is another easy dplyr way in a single filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an exclamation point in front of `variable` will do the trick.

```
filteredData <- unfilteredData %>% filter(!variable %in% (1000:2000))
```

This is just "not variable in range".

Alternatively, as Adam points out

```
filteredData <- unfilteredData %>%
         filter(variable < 1000) %>%
         filter(variable > 2000)
```

Is also a viable approach. Multiple ways roads lead to Rome!

Comment: That was my first instinct, but this isn't "not in range". It's actually "not in `c(1000, 1001, 1002, ..., 2000)`" which probably isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using mtcars example:

```
> mtcars %>% filter(!(hp %in% (100:200)))
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
>
```

We are excluding vehicles having hp between 100 and 200.